# c++: Passing lambdas with parameters to functions

Tags: c++, lambda

I am continuing my studies of C++ and I came across lambdas.
I am following a simple tutorial just to get a feel for the sintax, but the following code is failing:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void runDivide(double (*divide)(double a, double b)) {
    auto rval = divide(a , b);
    cout << rval << endl;
}

int main() {

  auto funcDiv = [](double value1, double value2) -> double{
      if (value2 == 0.0) {
          return 0;
      }
      return value1 / value2;
  };

  runDivide(funcDiv);

  system("pause");

  return 0;
}
```

This is giving me a "Identifier 'a' is undefined" and "Identifier 'b' is undefined". Although I am copying it verbatin from the tutorial, maybe I'm missing something?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Michael

Comment: You forgot to pass the function arguments.

Comment: There's no variables `a` and `b` in `runDivide()`.

Comment: Instead of copying try to understand what the code does. If you understood, then you'd understand that `a` and `b` aren't defined anywhere. They're simply in the type of the function pointer.

Comment: Thanks for this. I thought I had understood it but I can see now that I had developed "tunnel vision" and missed this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`runDivide()` uses the variables `a` and `b`, but never declares them or gives them values. They should be arguments to `runDivide`, not part of the declaration of the function argument (you don't need to give names to those arguments, just declare the types).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void runDivide(double (*divide)(double, double), double a, double b) {
    auto rval = divide(a , b);
    cout << rval << endl;
}

int main() {

  auto funcDiv = [](double value1, double value2) -> double{
      if (value2 == 0.0) {
          return 0;
      }
      return value1 / value2;
  };

  runDivide(funcDiv, 30.0, 12.3);

  system("pause");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems obvious now (hindsight and all). I guess because I'm new to this aspect of C++, I got confused with the difference between the type of the function pointer and the paremeter names themselves!

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to name parameters in a function pointer, like here:

```
double (*divide)(double a, double b)
```

The name `a` and `b` are names of the two `double`s that the function that the function pointer `divide` points to.

However, such names have **no impact on the behavior of your code** in C++.

```
double (*divide)(double, double)
```

This has exactly the same meaning.

`divide` is a function pointer that points at a function that takes two `double`s and returns one `double`.

```
void runDivide(double (*divide)(double, double)) {
  auto rval = divide(a , b);
  cout << rval << endl;
}
```

this makes it far more obvious that `a` and `b` have no meaning at this point.

You either need to pass `double a` and `double b` to `runDivide`, or have them visible in the scope of `runDivide`.

This "the function parameter names have no effect" is true both with function pointers and with function declarations (but not with function definitions or lambda definitions).

To fix this change

```
runDivide(funcDiv);
```

to

```
runDivide(funcDiv,1.0, 2.0);
```

and

```
void runDivide(double (*divide)(double, double)) {
  auto rval = divide(a , b);
  cout << rval << endl;
}
```

to

```
void runDivide(double (*divide)(double, double), double a, double b) {
  auto rval = divide(a , b);
  cout << rval << endl;
}
```

Alternatively, simply add global variables `double a` and `double b` before `runDivide`, and set them to something reasonable.  I would consider that a bad idea, as global variables are a mess.

Answer (score 0):

The only argument to `runDivide` is `divide`. The `a` and `b` are not used and can be left out. They are just place holders for the arguments of the passed in function.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you cannot normally make a call from one function to another function's arguments. Due to the fact they can be accessed only within the specific function, you must declare these arguments/variables globally. Next thing you forgot to declare them in further part of the code.